# getting info from dataset and putting in worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

I am having some issues with the following:

I give my method a dataset and it is supposed to throw the information into an excel file, which is a template of the formatting I desire. The excel file i created has a header, some filters and things of the sort, and  I set my method to populate the file AFTER the header, etc but the problem is, when I do that, I lose all the formatting i had on the template. I am using this class http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/biffcsharp.aspx . Im not sure, it may be that the format for the implementation of the class is a real simple one or that it overwrites all the information I had.

my method looks like this, using the class on the link above :

```
public void PopularSheet()
{     
    string filename = "C:\\test"  + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SYSTEMCLIENTID"].ToString()+ System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["SYSTEMUSERTYPEID"].ToString()+ System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["CLIENTID"].ToString()+".xls";
    File.Copy("C:\\test.xls", filename);
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    ExcelWriter writer = new ExcelWriter(stream);
    DataSet ds = GetDataSet();
    writer.BeginWrite();

    int jValue = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
    int iValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;

    // Passa os dados do dataset para a planilha
    for (int i = 0; i < iValue; i++)
    {
        // Lê todas as colunas da linha i
        for (int j = 0; j < jValue; j++)
        {
            writer.WriteCell(i+2, j, ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString());


        }
    }
    writer.EndWrite();
    stream.Close();
}
```

I also tried using an excel library,http://www.carlosag.net/tools/excelxmlwriter/,but i think in order to LOAD a file (so that i can insert the information i need into it) i need to load a xml file, which is impossible!

Another library I used presented a problem when saving, I was able to edit the worksheet and then when i saved and opened the excel file that was generated thru the code, it would come out empty .

I cannot use anything that will force me to install excel, which is why i am trying these alternatives. Are there any suggestions to what I could do?

What i need to do :

- Load an existing excel file as "template"
- Throw a dataset into the file
- Save the file with the information that i threw with the template format

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com/) which is useful for creating openxml file.

Answer (score 0):

Quick thought: can you use a .csv instead of a standard .xls file?
If so, you can easily fill your table.